# how to find percentage and save it to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$ar1=array("Mobile","shop","software","hardware");
$arr2=arry("shop","Mobile","shop","software","shop")
```

i want to compare the elements of arr2 to arr1 i.e

```
    $counts=array();
    foreach($arr2 as $val)
    { 
        if(in_array($val, $arr1))
        {    
          array_push($counts,$val);
          // here will my insert query to insert data in mysql table.
        }
     } //end of foreach loop
  $specific_fields = array_count_values($counts); /* Array ( [shop] => 3 [software] => 1 [Mobile] => 1)
         $total_fields=count($arr2);  // output will be 5

Now here first i want to find percentage for each element
i.e    $per1=$specific_fields['shop']/$total_fields;
       $per2=$per1*100;
        $percentage=number_format($per2,0);

when i find the percentage how can i update below query with the percentage values of all elements.

    $query="update table_name set shop='$percentage_value',Mobile='$percentage_value'.......";
     }
```

Is there a dynamic way to update all the fields automatically.

Comment: Generally speaking it's not good practice to save changing derived values to a relational db.  It's much more effective to save the incoming raw values and use a query to calculate the derived values when you need them. This has 2 advantages- no UPDATEs, only INSERTs; and the ability to use the raw data in many different kinds of calculations.

One of the few times it's worth saving changing derived values is for summary tables, which can act as a sort of cache for the results of expensive queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PDO and prepared statements, and also at MySQL prepared statements.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html

Comment: Do you mean calculate it in the query? If so, have a look at my other answer.

Comment: i don't want to calculate in to the query. First i want to calculate percentage for each elemnt i.e `shop, Mobile, software` then update query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the COUNT function. Example:`update table_name set shop=(COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE column meets condition)/(COUNT(*) FROM table_name) * 100, Mobile = ...`
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$specific_fields = array_map(function($val, $total_fields){
  return $val / count($total_fields)
}, $specific_fields, [$arr2]);

print_r($specific_fields);
```

For update sql statement should be like

```
$str_temp = '';
foreach ($specific_fields as $key => $f)
{
  $str_temp .= "$key=$f"
}

$sql = "UPDATE ... SET $str_temp WHERE ID = <ID>"
```